# Spring Boot - EventListener not loaded by WebApplicationInitializer (Tomcat no embedded)

Tags: spring-boot, servletcontextlistener

I need to start a spring boot project in an external Tomcat (no embedded). The application starts by defining, as per documentation, the necessary interfaces. The problem is that added listeners are never invoked (I'm referring to the `contextInitialized` method never called). I don't understand where the error is, I have tried several solutions to no avail:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder = builder.sources(TestApplication.class);
        return applicationBuilder;
    }
}
```

The TestWebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class TestWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Going to debug, the interface is called correctly:

```
public class TestWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(TestWebConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        servletContext.addListener(new TestListener()); // <--- this is the problem

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(TestApplication .class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

This is the listener that is not being invoked. I also tried with the `@WebListener` and `@ServletComponentScan` annotation but nothing. I have read that only the embedded Tomcat works.

```
public class TestListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent ctx) {
        logger.info("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0){
    }
}
```

I also tried to declare the listener with the `@Bean`, as suggested in a post, still nothing or do an `@Autowired` in the WebApplicationInitializer to not pass it with `new`, still nothing.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Remove your `TestWebApplicationInitializer`, remove your `TestWebConfig` add `@Component` to `TestLIstener`. Restart.

Comment: Sorry correct, yes now it works (I left a typo), thanks! Even though I expected `ServletListenerContext` to be invoked before an `ApplicationContextInitializer` (I have one configured), as was the case in classic web.xml configurations. Does it depend on Servlet 3.0 by any chance?

Comment: No it is the `WebApplicationContextInitializer` that registers it as it is (indirectly) an implementation of the `ServletContainerInitializer`. Which basically is the java variant of the `web.xml`.